# How to do a looped animation with correct rotation using Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Recently I am learning Geometry Nodes. I follow a tutorial and create a swimming fish but I want to loop it.

Currently the fish loops correctly in position but once I add rotation node, the head doesn't rotate as expected and whole fish is smashed in frame 125. Using curve can also solve the problem  but I want to figure it out with procedural calculation. Is there any method to solve this?

Thank you so much!:D

[image]

Node tree:[image]

File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g800uv1j1mmq71a/fish_NC.blend?dl=0

Tutorial I followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvHLQGUo-y4&t=263s&ab_channel=Bbbn19

Comment: I see you are new here. Welcome! There is a feature built in to Stack Exchange for uploading and adding images to your post. Please use it. Otherwise, if your Dropbox file ever gets removed, how will anyone be able to see your reference image? I tried to fix that for you, but your animated GIF is 13.6MB (well over the 2MB upload limit). You are not making an HD film here, so re-export your animation at a lower resolution and maybe skip every other frame as well (Output Properties > Frame Range > Step). If the image is displayed too large, use the HTML syntax: `<img src="path" width="420"/>`

Comment: Similarly, there is a way to host your .blend files *that  are part of Blender Stack Exchange posts*. It is [blend-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com/) But if you are going to use it, be mindful of the size of your .blend files, so as not to waste the hosting space that is generously provided by the site owner to the BSE community for free. Aim for 1 to 2 MB. If you are not sure how to keep your file sizes small, using Dropbox (as you are doing now) is also okay.

Comment: Thank you for reminding. A new gif is added. Unfortunately, I got an error when the file (1.8M) was uploaded on blender exchange. So I will leave it as it is.